# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_path'

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I want to generate screenshot using selenium and phantomjs.This is my code which I am executing from virtualenv (Python 2.7,Windows 8):

```
from selenium import webdriver
br = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe')
br.set_window_size(1376,768)
br.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
br.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
br.quit()
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\bunker\Lib\site-packages\custom_scn.py", line 58, in <module>
br = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe')
File "C:\bunker\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 49, in   __init__
service_args=service_args,log_path=service_log_path)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_path'
```

`PhantomJs` is at path `C:\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe`.How to do debug this :(

Comment: What does `PhantomJS` expect to take?

Comment: Try setting a value for **log_path** in **webdriver.PhantomJS** invocation

Comment: what value should I set?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value of log_path as:

`log_path = os.devnull`